# Spark cache is not working properly

Tags: scala, caching, apache-spark, rdd

I tried to use cache() to keep my data on memory.
I set some properties to make sure enough memory to keep both rddA and rddB.
But somehow rddA is not made when it should made and myFunction works 2 times.

```
def myFunction = println(".") // to check when It works

var rddA = myFuntion().cache() 
var rddB = rddA.map({ do somethings}).cache() // I though rddA made in cache here

rddB.map({ real work }) // printed "."
...
...
rddA.map({ other works}) // printed "." again why??
```

Comment: I suggest you add the tag spark to get help faster

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile - looks like you over simplified it for the example... should `myFuntion().cache()` be changed to `rdd.map(a => { myFunction(); a }).cache()`??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are calling `cache()` on `myFunction` in your code sample there and you don't seem to be materialising the RDD, so I'm not really clear what is going wrong for you. Here is a simple example to show cache() working in a local context:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("my-spark-test").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rddA = sc.wholeTextFiles("*.txt").map(_._2)

val rddB = rddA.map(x => {
  println("*** RUNNING ***")
  x
}).cache()

val xs = rddB.collect()
val ys = rddB.collect()
```

This will print `*** RUNNING ***` to the console just once, but if you remove the cache() call from the end of the definition of rddB it will print `*** RUNNING ***` twice.